# android studio share media (images and video) from webview

Tags: java, android, image, webview, share

Could you please help me ?
Indeed, I've developped a webapp which aim is to share pics and videos.
Now I would like to turn this webapp into an android app. To do this, I've managed to load my webapp into a webview.
So far, everything's ok. I've set javascript enabled to true and it works fine.

But trouble comes it file sharing. Indeed, I need to be able to share the pics and videos.
Using Chrome, there's no problem. "navigator.share" works just fine. But it's not compatible with webview.

I've added a javascriptinterface to my android app so I can get the media url of my files. With that url I thought I could easily share my medias but... no.
I tried to use the picasso library but it's not working properly.

I've also set the following permissions in the AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I always get the error "Method call should not happen from the main thread".

I don't know how to get through this.
Could please somebody help me ?

Thanks a lot,
Damien

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mBibouView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        mBibouView=findViewById(R.id.bibouview);

        mBibouView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mBibouView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mBibouView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mBibouView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mBibouView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        mBibouView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mBibouView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptShareInterface(), "AndroidShareHandler");

        mBibouView.loadUrl("https://www.myadress.fr");


    }


    public class JavascriptShareInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void share(String url){

            Target target = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    Bitmap bmp = bitmap;
                    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, "SomeText", null);
                    Log.d("Path", path);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey view/download this image");
                    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."));
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            };
            Picasso.with(Principal.this).load(url).into(target);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        mBibouView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('div_form').style.display='none';",null);
        mBibouView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('div_menu').style.display='none';",null);

        /**   if(mBibouView.canGoBack()){
           // mBibouView.goBack();

        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
      **/
    }

}
```

Comment: `Method call should not happen from the main thread` Which method? Which statement does that?

Comment: `Log.d("Path", path);` Please tell the path value that is logged.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, the error is caused by the following statement: Picasso.with(Principal.this).load(url).into(target);

Comment: Then did you try already to put that statement in the run() of the Runnable of a new Thread?

Comment: new Thread (new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Picasso.with(Principal.this).load(url).into(target);
                        }}).start();